# How can I associate the .csv file extension with Google Sheets?

Tags: windows, file-association, google-spreadsheets

When I click on a .csv file in a browser on my Windows PC, Microsoft Excel automatically starts with the .csv file opened in it.  How can I change my machine or browser settings so that Google Sheets starts instead of Excel?

Comment: Per the `google-spreadsheets` tag info, this question is on topic at Super user since it *specifically involve[s the] computer*.

Answer (score 3):

Google Docs and Sheets are in-browser only, so the traditional Windows "Open With" isn't going to work.  You might be able to script something with the steps "Open a browser to Google Sheets, New Sheet, copy over this document" and associate the file type with the script.
I know of three ways to manually open a local doc in Google Docs or Sheets : You have to open a Google Drive window and drag the document there, or use the Google Drive or Google Sheets UI to open/upload the document, or have the Windows app Google Drive and move the file inside your Drive directory.

Comment: so the crux of the problem is that to view the document in Google Sheets I first have to be able to access it in the "Google space".  There is no one-click solution to download a csv file from a site, put it in google space and launching sheets.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [gamUploader](https://github.com/NoSubstitute/gamUploader), a compilable python script I created for Windows.

You simply associate csv with gamUploader and when you double-click a csv file, it will upload the file to your Drive and open it in the appropriate app in Chrome.

https://github.com/NoSubstitute/gamUploader

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.